# How to set text color in JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Does someone know how to set a part of text color in `JButton`?

For example:

My button has text: "I Love YOU."

Now, I want to draw only the word "**Love**" with **RED** color, and words "I" & "You" with black color.

What should I do for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML

```
new JButton("<html><center>I "
                 + "<font color=red>Love</font>"+"You</center></html>");
```

[image]

Comment: Note that HTML does not render as expected in a disabled button.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)